# Start Git-Flow repo from project dir or home dir?

Tags: git

I am using Git Flow and it is not clear from the documents whether I call 'git flow init' from my project root or from my home directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do 'git flow init' from your project root directory.

> you can start using git-flow in your repository by using it's init command

http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/why-arent-you-using-git-flow/

Comment: the confusion comes from the "in your repository" part. Other repositories like mvn store their local files in a subfolder of home dir. Thanks for your response!